# Botched upgrade--dpkg hangs on 'Started Braille Device Support'

Tags: apt, upgrade, hard-drive, dpkg, recovery-mode

Screwed up an upgrade from 14.10->15.04->15.10 badly.  I've been messing around in recovery mode and am confidentish that I managed to get all the broken packages/dependencies removed and reinstalled, but now I'm running into this queer issue.  Aptitude won't run, it says I need to do stuff with dpkg.  dpkg will do stuff, but always gets hung up on

```
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
[  OK  ] Started Braille Device Support.
```

This Braille hang has been plaguing me for a while, but I've finally reached an impasse.  The first part, with the errors, seems to be an obscure error relating to screwed up hard drives, and after some log digging, it seems as though it may me pointing to the Windows partition on this HD, which is fine.  That seems like a dead end, and I can't find anything else on it online.

I'd really like to not have to backup, reformat, and reinstall.  Does anybody have a lead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just got into a similar situation with a botched upgrade and subsequent messing around in recovery mode, where a certain subset of packages (namely apport) were hanging on `dpkg --configure -a` with that same `Started Braille Device Support.` message. The hack that got me through this was:

1. If you're currently staring at a hung `apt-get` command, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop. If that doesn't work (as it did for me), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then run `kill -9 %1` a couple times to kill it off for good. Then run `rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`, since you murdered the process that usually does that.
2. Run `screen` (in order to get more than one prompt).
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>c</kbd> to open a different prompt.
4. Run `dpkg --configure -a` and wait for the process to hang.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>a</kbd> to switch back to the other prompt.
6. Run `killall systemctl`
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>a</kbd> to switch back to the `dpkg --configure -a` command.
8. Note that the last package should have finished configuring, and `dpkg` has moved on to the next package and hung in the same fashion, or completed.
9. If `dpkg` is hanging again, goto step 5.
10. Once `dpkg --configure -a` is finally done, proceed mucking around in recovery mode, possibly running `apt-get upgrade` until the system seems in a rebootable state.

As for why this worked (for me at least), my debug process was as follows:

1. `apt-get upgrade` was hanging. Run the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and `kill -9 %1` thing above to get back to the prompt.
2. Run `dpkg --configure -a`, and observe it hangs with the same `Started Braille Device Support.` message as `apt-get upgrade`. However, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works this time to return to prompt.
3. Search around for "ubuntu started braille device support". Find out from this [debian accessibility page](https://wiki.debian.org/accessibility) that it has to do with `brltty`.
4. Run `apt-get remove brltty`, maybe it'll make the problem go away.
5. Rerun `dpkg --configure -a` and notice that it *still* hangs, but this time, there's no message about `Started Braille Device Support`. OK.
6. Run `strace dpkg --configure -a`, and observe that the process is stuck on a `wait4(...)` call to a subprocess.
7. A couple strace lines upwards, note that the process writes the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.postinst` (or something similar, IIRC).
8. `less` the above file, and see it's attempting to restart a boot service. Posit that since we're in recovery mode and the init system hasn't run to completion, that's going to be awkward.
9. Run `pstree`, and see that `dpkg --reconfigure -a` did indeed fork to a `bash` thing, which then forks to `perl`, and finally `systemctl`, which does restart boot services, and may be confused.
10. Note that the `postinst` script doesn't have `set -e` in it, so maybe we can kill the hung command inside of it, so the shell script finishes and `dpkg` moves on.
11. Open another screen prompt, run `killall systemctl`, switch back, and see that `dpkg` did indeed move on. Great. It's stuck in the same place again though, on a different package.
12. Run `killall systemctl` again until `dpkg` exits.
13. Run `apt-get dist-upgrade` again, see that it says everything is up to date.
14. Cross my fingers, and reboot.

Miraculously, the system recovered, and so far has no issues.

So, it's not a complete reduction (why does systemctl hang in recovery mode?), nor is it likely generally applicable, but this hack and the process to discover it may help somebody who arrives at this page through a web search like I did.

Comment: I have even less idea than you why this worked, but it did!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/825929/589804 achieves the same thing with a single command and no need to install screen.

Answer (score 4):

An improvement to the previous answers when you cannot use the command `screen':

```
dpkg --configure -a & (sleep 2m; killall systemctl)
```

Change the sleep time to a minimum time interval after which you are quite certain that dpkg gets stuck. (In my case I, in fact, used 10s). Worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue when I tried upgrading 15.10 to 16.04 and I fixed using below steps.

1. Boot in command line by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> when highlight the first entry to edit it.
2. Cursor to the end of the `linux` line. Remove `quiet splash vt.handoff=7` and add `single`.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot.
4. Run `screen` (in order to get more than one prompt).
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>C</kbd> to open a different prompt.
6. Run `dpkg --configure -a` and wait to finish.
7. Reboot

Comment: Good answer +1. I have just one critique: `screen` isn't part of default Ubuntu installations and unnecessary here. I would argue that it's more confusing than helpful here – especially since running `screen` on a default installation will prompt the user to install it with `apt-get` which would likely fail if they're currently trying to resolve a package management issue.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to run the process mostly by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to pause the current process and send it to the background, followed by entering

```
killall systemctl
```

into the shell to terminate all `systemctl` processes and

```
fg
```

to continue the paused process again in foreground.

Comment: Works for me in Ubuntu 16.04 in recovery mode, thank you!